# Add dynamically jpanels

Tags: java, swing

I want to generate multiple panels (with title, desc and detail button), this is the general structure:

[image]

But when I put this code in a `for` loop it always adds the last item.

```
Panel panel_1 = new Panel();
panel_1.setBounds(23, 134, 378, 208);

JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("desc");
lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(0, 69, 189, 69);

JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Details");
btnNewButton_2.setBounds(104, 139, 189, 69);
panel_1.setLayout(null);

JLabel lblPrv = new JLabel("title");
lblPrv.setBounds(104, 0, 189, 69);
panel_1.add(lblPrv);
panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_2);

JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("");
label_1.setBounds(0, 69, 189, 69);
panel_1.add(label_1);

panel_1.add(btnNewButton_2);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please don't add tags into the title. I removed them for you.

Comment: Use a combination of layout managers, see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: *"I want to generate multiple panels (with title desc and detail button)"*  Use a `JList` with an appropriate `ListCellRenderer` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to place multiple panels next to each other:

[image]

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    Example() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            add(new MyPanel());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        MyPanel() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JLabel("title", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            add(new JLabel("<html>WWWWWW WWWWWWW<p>WWWWWWWWW<p>RRRRRRR RRRRR RRRRRRR"));
            add(new JButton("Details"), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Example());
    }
}
```

You should pick the layout managers best suited for your situation.

Comment: how wrap every time?

Comment: and if i want to modify jlabels text of a certain panel ?

Comment: @Fr4ncx Keep a reference to the label and call its `setText` method.

Comment: @Fr4ncx What you are saying is impossible. A component can only be added to one container. Do you need to change the text during runtime or do you have predefine text that you want to load?